# How many stops are there at a given state in this Markov chain after $n$ steps?

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

Consider a two-state Markov chain with the corresponding transition matrix
$$
P = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{5}{8}&\frac{3}{8} \\\frac{3}{8}&\frac{5}{8}\\ \end{bmatrix}.
$$
Given an equal chance of starting at either state, how many stops will there be on average at the first state (corresponding to the first entry of the probability vector) after $n$ stages/steps?

The initial condition for this problem is given by $\mathbf{p}(0) = (1/2, 1/2)$ but I cannot figure out how to proceed from here. Any hints on where to start are appreciated.

Comment: What is $p(1)$?

Comment: $\mathbf{p}(1) = P\mathbf{p}(0)$

Comment: Maybe I was just suggesting to evaluate $p(1)$ and see if, from there, you can find the value of $p(n)$.